# Asmselect and changing selected status of an option with Javascript

Tags: jquery, dynamic, selected, asmselect

I'm trying to do a fairly simple task in asmselect with no luck.

I have a multiple select list using asmselect. None of the options are selected initially.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="myselectdiv" name="myselectdiv[]" title="choose">
<option value="0">zero</option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Asmselect is initialized correctly and I can watch items appear below as I select them manually.

I want to use Javascript or jQuery to change the selected status of one of the options to "selected", dynamically, without clicking the option. This is really basic :

```
document.getElementById('myselectdiv').options[3].selected=true;
```

When I try to do this on a multiple select list, with asmselect initialized, nothing happens. I want the javascript to select the item and have it appear below, as it does when clicking it manually with asmselect.

Same problem on Safari 5 and Firefox 21, MacOS. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation I was able to resolve the problem. I'm posting the solution in case somebody is having the same issue.

Documentation describes initializing asmSelect at the time the document loads, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("select[multiple]").asmSelect({
   addItemTarget: 'bottom',
   animate: true,
   highlight: true,
   sortable: true
   });          
});
```

But if you plan to populate and/or change the selected items dynamically with javascript, after the page loads, asmSelect needs to be un-initialized when changes are made, and then re-initialized. For example:

```
function something() {
   [do some ajax]

   // remove the asmSelect attachment to the select list
   $(".asmSelect").remove(); $(".asmList").remove();

   //change some selections in the list with Javascript
   document.getElementById('myselectlist').options[3].selected=true;

   // re-initialize asmSelect
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("select[multiple]").asmSelect({
     addItemTarget: 'bottom',
     animate: true,
     highlight: true,
     sortable: true
     });            
   }); 
}
```

Overall I'm very happy with asmSelect and I hope this post is helpful to others implementing the tool.